# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}=0\,$?

Tags: limits

What is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$?

If this value tends to zero, how can I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: "how to prove it" Presumably by using the definition. Try that. Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to proof this. 
It depends on what you already know.

If you know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}=0=\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac1n$ then since

$-\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\leq \frac{1}{n}$

It is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}=0$ by the squeezing theorem.

Or simply since the sequence $a_n=\frac1n$ converges to $0$ and $(-1)^n$ is bounded (by $\pm 1$) your sequence in question is a null sequence.

Also you can go straight by definition. In that case you can more likly copy the proof of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that if $\sum a_n$ **converges**, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$. Using the alternating series test method, we know that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges.

Hence, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=0$.

Comment: This seems dangerously circular. What exactly was the alternating series test method, again?

Comment: I think that even if this works it is basically an overkill for such an elementary problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what causes you trouble is the $(-1)^n$ term in the numerator. I also suppose that you already know that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$, so I will show you how to compute this limit without using the squeeze theorem or using some overly complicated series test.
Consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$, $x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. We are going to show that the subsequences $(x_{2n})_{n\ge 1}$ and $(x_{2n+1})_{n\ge 1}$ both converge to the same limit, which is $0$.
We have that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_{2n}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2n}=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_{2n+1}=-\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}=0$.
Since $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}=(x_{2n})_{n\ge 1} \cup (x_{2n+1})_{n\ge 1}$, it follows that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_{n}=0$.
P.S.: I also assumed that you are not looking for a proof by using the epsilon definition. In the future, please give more information when asking a question.